# How do I add data to text file and not overwrite what I have in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

This is my code so far but it overwrites what I have in the text file already. What I want is for it to add it to a new line in the text file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner s1,s2;
    s1 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("login.txt"));
    s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loggedIn = false;
    String name,pword,n,p;
    System.out.println("Are you a new user? (Type y for yes or n for no)");
    String nU = s2.next();

    if (nU.equals("n"))
    {
    System.out.println("Enter username:");
    n=s2.next();
    System.out.println("Enter password:");
    p=s2.next();
    while(s1.hasNext()){
      name=s1.next();
      pword=s1.next();
      if(n.equals(name) && p.equals(pword)){
        System.out.println("You are logged in.");
        loggedIn = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!loggedIn)
      System.out.println("Incorrect password or username.");
    }
    else if (nU.equals("y"))
    {
```

Down here is where the problem with my code will be as this is where it is writing it to the file.

```
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("login.txt"); 
     System.out.println("Enter username:");
     n=s2.next();
     System.out.println("Enter password:");
     p=s2.next();
     out.append(n);
     out.append(p);
     out.close();
     System.out.println("Account has been created and you are logged in.");
    }
    else
      System.out.println("Invalid response.");
```

Comment: u can read that data then stored into the string and merge the other string with it and write it :)

Answer (score 11):

It is advised to use chain of  `BufferedWriter` and `FileWriter`, and the key point is `FileWriter` will append String to current file when use the one of its constructor that lets appaneding by adding `true` to last paramter like

```
new FileWriter("login.txt", true)
```

and when we surrounding it with `BufferedWriter` object in order to be more efficient if you are going to write in the file number of time, so it buffers the string in big chunk and write the big chunk into a file and clearly you can save a lot of time for writing into a file

**Note** :It is possible not to use `BuffredWriter` ,but it is advised because of better performance and ability to buffer the big chunk of Strings and write them once

Just change your

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("login.txt");
```

to

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("login.txt", true)));
```

Example:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("login.txt", true)));) {
    String data = "This content will append to the end of the file";
    File file = new File("login.txt");
    out.println(data);
} catch(IOException e) {
}
```

It is possible to solve this issue without using `BufferedWriter`, yet the performance will be low as I mentioned.

Example:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("login.txt", true));) {
    String data = "This content will append to the end of the file";
    File file = new File("login.txt");
    out.println(data);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Your "true" option to the PrintWriter constructor will only flush the buffer. It doesn't mean change to append mode.

Comment: boolean append is for FileWriter not for PrintWriter... One of PrintWriter class constructor is not FileWriter....the boolean append "true" has to be specified as part of FileWriter not as part of PrintWriter

Comment: @HAR I posted some explanation hope you are happy now ;)

Comment: Good answer. Your explanation sounds legitimate. A sidenote: leaving empty catch clause is almost always a bad idea. Only trivial examples are eligible to have them in my opinion. I'd recommend to log an exception, then handle if applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Use [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true);
//the true will append the new data to the existing data
```

Something like this

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                         new FileWriter("login.txt", true)))
out.println(n);
out.println(p);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example is this.

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("Current working directory : " + workingDir);
File file = new File(workingDir+"/WebContent/Files/login.txt");
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true)));
printWriter.println(workingDir);
printWriter.println("Good thing");
printWriter.close();
```

hope it helps.