# Writing an ArrayList via a constructor into a txt file

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I have been able to add an ArrayList into a text file while at the main method. But when I tried to make a constructor that has a method that takes an ArrayList  and add it to the text file giving to the constructor .I get all kind of errors. could someone please give me an advice on what I could be doing wrong thank you Im new to java so please no big words.

```
public class RXTWriter {

    private String filename;

    public RXTWriter(String afilename) {
        filename = afilename;
    }

    public void addtext(ArrayList<String> line) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(filename);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter momo = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter xoxo = new BufferedWriter(momo);

        for (int k = 0; k < line.size(); k++) {
            xoxo.write(line.get(k) + "\n");
            xoxo.close();
            System.out.println("Data saved.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: i had the wrong code in sorry

Comment: @momo what is the right one? what is the error you get?

Comment: Please, **1** Indent your code properly and copy-paste it over the one you gave us. **2** Explain what this is supposed to do. **3** Give us the exact error messages you get.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:98)
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:203)
 at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
 at RXTWriter.addtext(RXTWriter.java:30)
 at testin.main(testin.java:22)
Those errors

Comment: Put the errors inside the question, please. And use the `{}` button to properly format them.

Comment: Is this the code which is not working??

Comment: Don't close the file after writing each line. Close your files, even if your code throws an exception. Read about the try-with-resources construct. Read about the enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the for loop, you write first line and you close it after that, so you will lose your connection to the file

```
        for (int k = 0; k < line.size(); k++) {
            xoxo.write(line.get(k) + "\n");
            xoxo.close();
            System.out.println("Data saved.");
        }
```

it seems you wanted something like this

```
           for (int k = 0; k < line.size(); k++) {
               xoxo.write(line.get(k) + "\n");
            }
            xoxo.close();
            System.out.println("Data saved.");
```

Comment: yes thank you Kick it works now but unfortunately it only saves the first sting of the ArrayList.

Comment: you should activate the append feature lemme give you a link to one of my answer

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540751/how-do-i-add-data-to-text-file-and-not-overwrite-what-i-have-in-java/25540826#25540826

Comment: I found that in a rush I was looking to a different txt file what you firs did taking the .close out of the loop made it work perfectly.Thank you. as for the link thank you Im truing to approach the idea in a different way.

Comment: Happy to help
See the @David Conrad comment too. he point out good points to be more optimized an up to date